# Open embedded pdf to a certain page

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I've embedded a PDF into my workbook, and I need a code which will open the embedded PDF to a certain page.

The PDF needs to be embedded in the worksheet as it must be sent outside the organisation; I don't want to send a ZIP file with worksheets and PDFs.

So far, this is what I have in order to open the embedded PDF, and this works fine at the moment.

"Object 2" is the name of the embedded PDF.

```
 Sub Macro1()

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Object 2").Select

    Selection.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary

 End Sub
```

If someone could help for opening the PDF to a certain page that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
Public Sub InsertPdf(PdfFileName As String)
Dim b As OLEObject

    Set b = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(fileName:=PdfFileName, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False)
    b.Left = 0
    b.Top = 0

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
After careful reading once again I think here is the code you need:

```
Public Function OpenPdf(SheetName As String)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim shp As Shape

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName)

    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
           shp.Select
           Selection.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary
           Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Usage:

```
OpenPdf("Sheet2")
```

Comment: I tested it now on Excel 2010 and it works fine. Call: `InsertPdf "c:\temp\test.pdf"` inserts on active sheet test.pdf and it is embedded inside file. Could you provide error message or what exactly is not working? Maybe I misundertood what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi @smartobelix, this code won't open up to a specific page.

Comment: Have you tried function OpenPdf - is it what are you searching for?